# Spring - How to add a session attribute only once per session

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Spring Boot application I add the user name as a custom session attribute. I did this so in the Tomcat manager I can see who is currently using the app:

[image]

I implemented javax.servlet.Filter to add the user name. But is this the recommended way to do that? After all, the attribute gets added on every single request. Does Spring provide a callback which is executed only once per session?

Answer (score 1):

Once you add an attribute to `HttpSession` , that attribute will keep existing in the session provided that the session does not expiry or you do not remove it from the session. So I don't see the point of implementing a `Filter` to add an attribute to the `HttpSession` for every request as this attribute is already exist in the session since you add it.

Besides , what you are doing is already done by Spring Security (p.s. in the [`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#security-context-persistence-filter)) and I would not do it one more time by myself. Actually that session attribute `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` is the same object as we use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` to access the current login user information.

That means if the `Authentication` object that is set into the `SecurityContextHolder` has its `toString()` implemented to print the username (such as [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/e15922322ea7de1c1087f8a8e97c37b9724dd04f/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.java#L224)), you could also see the username in the `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` session attribute in Tomcat Manager.

Comment: The Authentication object is of type waffle.spring.WindowsAuthenticationToken. Do you mean I should extend that class and implement its toString()? How would the extended object then be wired with the Spring context? So far, the authentication is created by adding this to my properties file: waffle.sso.enabled=true

Comment: Yes. Most probably need to extend `AuthenticationProvider` provided by waffle and return a customised `WindowsAuthenticationToken` from there. Another option is to implement an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` to listen to the authentication success event and simply add the username to the session.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, waffle is not really extension-friendly. Extending WindowsAuthenticationToken and WindowsAuthenticationProvider is no use because they set their own implementation on every request in their own filter (NegotiateSecurityFilter).The other option, implementing AuthenticationSuccessHandler, is probably the way to go, although I could not figure out yet how to make waffle use DelegatingNegotiateSecurityFilter.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC has tools for dealing with sessions and the @SessionAttributes section of this tutorial actually discusses registering a bean with Session scope so that it is called for each new session.

[more info here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-session-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

I wondered this too.

*What's the Spring-way to add session attributes (specifically related to Spring Security authentication)?*

In my case, I registered a bean listening for Spring Security's `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` and `SessionDestroyedEvent` events. These events fire without any explicit configuration in a default Spring Boot environment.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.security:

> The basic features you get by default in a web application are:
>
> - . . .
> - A DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher for publishing authentication events.

This way I could add "username" as a session attribute immediately after a user logons and remove that attribute when the security session (security context) is destroyed:

```
@Component
public class SessionStoreUsernameAuthEventHandler {

  @EventListener
  public void audit(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent e) {
    getSession().ifPresent(s -> s.setAttribute("username", e.getAuthentication().getName()));
  }

  @EventListener
  public void audit(SessionDestroyedEvent e) {
    getSession().ifPresent(s -> s.removeAttribute("username"));
  }
  
  private static Optional<HttpServletRequest> getCurrentRequest() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
      .filter(ServletRequestAttributes.class::isInstance)
      .map(ServletRequestAttributes.class::cast)
      .map(ServletRequestAttributes::getRequest);
  }

  private static Optional<HttpSession> getSession() {
    return getCurrentRequest().map(HttpServletRequest::getSession);
  }
}
```